# Error with pattern while running example pattern.web.HTTP403Forbidden

Tags: python, anaconda

I am working with **Debian.** I have installed **Anaconda**, then I created a virtual environment with **Python2.7**, and finally according with [Pattern Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/asmeurer/pattern) I installed pattern by typing `conda install -c asmeurer pattern` 
When I try to run the first example from here [Pattern Clips](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern)  I have the followinf error:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pattern.web import Twitter, plaintext
>>> twitter = Twitter(language='en')
>>> for tweet in twitter.search('"more important than"', cached=False):
...     print plaintext(tweet.text)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern/web/__init__.py", line 1471, in search
    data = url.download(cached=cached, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern/web/__init__.py", line 420, in download
    data = self.open(timeout, proxy, user_agent, referrer, authentication).read()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/venv27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern/web/__init__.py", line 381, in open
    if e.code == 403: raise HTTP403Forbidden(src=e)
pattern.web.HTTP403Forbidden
>>>
```

Any idea what is happening ? Thank you in advance

Comment: The exception would indicate that the Twitter server has responded with a [http 403 status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). My guess is that the example code you have found relies on an old Twitter API that is no longer available.

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of `pattern` that tries to access twitter without `https`? https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/68

Comment: I have checked the Twitter set up and it was updated and also it was using `https` .Thank you for the ideas. I updated the `pattern` version directly from `github` and the example that I was trying to run is working now

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by installing `Pattern` directly from `github`. In order to do so I had to remove the `Pattern` version I had already installed in my virtual environment by `conda remove pattern` and then `pip install git+git://github.com/clips/pattern`